# Accessing local resources using activex dll control in C#

Tags: c#, security, browser, activex

Its possible access local resources, like serial ports, open a socket, write a file, etc, using a activex dll in c#?
I already have a applicaton that works in this scenario, but i  had to configurate the framework to fulltrust access.  Now i would like to do without this configuration? It possible? There is a type of sign to certificate browser that is activex secure?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  However the user will have to install this ActiveX component in order to gain this functionality.  It is a good idea to sign your ActiveX Components but it is not necessary.   If you allow arbitrary reading and writing of files then this is a vulnerability.

For instance an attacker will want to use this ActiveX component to upload a .exe or .bat file to the startup folder.